# Recursion Functions - Removing special characters

Tags: c++, recursion, lambda

I am needing a function that removes special characters in a string. I am creating a program that takes in a sentence and counts the vowels and determines if its palindrome. But I need to delete special characters if there is any. I was using a lambda but it is not compatible with the compiler I am using and that is where my professor wants our programs to compile. So if anyone has another function I can use, I'd appreciate it very much. 
These are the errors I get :
 error: expected primary-expression before â[â token
 error: expected primary-expression before â]â token
 error: expected primary-expression before âcharâ
I commented on the line above where the errors are located.

```
 #include<iostream> 
    #include <cmath>
    #include <algorithm>


    using namespace std;

    //Create a structure called Sentence
    struct Sentence
    {
        int CountVowels(string , int);

        public:
        Sentence (string);
        bool isPal(string , int);
        void Print();
        string s;
        int numVowel;
        int length;
        //~Sentence();

    };

    Sentence :: Sentence (string b)
    {
        s = b;
        length = 0;
        numVowel = CountVowels(s, 0);
    }

    //Count Vowels function using recursion 
    int Sentence :: CountVowels(string myWord, int startindex)
    {
        length ++;
        int pandi; 

        if(myWord[startindex])
        {
            if (myWord[startindex] != 'a' && myWord[startindex] != 'e' && myWord[startindex] != 'i' && myWord[startindex] != 'o' && myWord[startindex] != 'u')
            {
                pandi = 0;
            }
        else pandi = 1;
        return pandi + CountVowels(myWord, startindex + 1);
        } 
        return 0;
    }

    // Check if it palindorme using recursion 
    bool Sentence :: isPal(string myWord, int size)
    {
        int r = myWord.size() - size;
        int t = size - 1;

        //size = r will be true whenn the size of the string is even and the 2 middle characters have been checked
        if (size == r || r == t)

            return true;
        //r = t will be true when the size of the string is odd and the two characters on either side of the middle character have been checked



        if (tolower(myWord[r]) != tolower(myWord[t]))

            return false;


        return isPal(myWord, -- size);
    }

    //Display the sentence 
    void Sentence :: Print()
    {
        cout << s [-- length];
        if (length == 0)
        {
            cout << "" << endl;
            return;

        }
        Print ();
    }

    //Main function 

    int main ()
    {
        //Holds user sentence 
        string userW;

        //Ask user to enter a sentence 
        cout << "Enter a sentence: \n";
        getline(cin, userW);
        //Removes special characters 
        //This is where the ERRORS are 
        userW.erase(remove_if(userW.begin(), userW.end(), [](char c) 
        {return !isalpha(c); }), userW.end());

        //Creates userSent under Sentence 
        Sentence userSent(userW);

        //Display the number of vowels
        cout << "The number of vowels in the sentence is " << userSent.numVowel << endl;
        cout << "" << endl;

        //Display if the sentence is a palindrome or not 
        cout << "The sentence" << " is" << 
        (userSent.isPal(userSent.s, userSent.s.size()) ? " Palindrome\n" : " not Palindrome\n");
        cout << "" << endl; 
        //Display the sentence backwards 
        cout << "The sentence spelled backwards is: " << endl;
        userSent.Print();

        return 0;
    }
```

Comment: Do you know how antique your professor's compiler is?

Answer (score 3):

A lambda is just a shorthand way of defining a class. You can always define a similar class without a lambda if you choose. For example, a lambda expression like this<sup>1</sup> (where `a` and `b` are of type `A` and `B` respectively):

```
[&a, =b](char c) { return a.x() + b > c; }
```

...can be defined as an explicit class something like this:

```
class foo { 
    A mutable &a;
    B b;
public:
    foo(A &a, B b) : a(a), b(b) {}

    bool operator()(char c) const { return a.x() + b > c; }
};
```

This is obviously much more verbose (which a lot of why lambda expressions were added) but does roughly the same things.

---

<sup>1. This isn't intended to be useful, just to include both kinds of capture *and* a parameter.</sup>

Comment: Shouldn't `bool operator()(char c)` be `const`, and the `A &a` `mutable`?

Comment: @vsoftco: Yeah--I was't trying to be all that accurate since neither is typically really needed in practice, but it clearly doesn't hurt either.

Answer (score 0):

Jeffry's answer explains how to avoid lambda in general if you need to. However, in this particular there is a one-line that does not need lambda. Replace the problematic line with:

```
  userW.erase(std::copy_if(userW.begin(), userW.end(), userW.begin(), isalpha), userW.end());
```

If it does not work, then your compiler has issues with STL, not only with lambda.

Comment: I replaced the line and I got an error saying ** no matching function for call copy_if

Comment: @mb13 If you did `#include <algorithm>`, then definitely, as I said,  your compiler has issues with STL. What I can confirm for you is that your code works fine (with and without lambda) for me with VS2015.

Comment: Yeah, I always use cpp.sh and it usually always works for me. But thank you for the help